# phpMyAdmin SQL Statement to expand or collapse group by

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm experiencing a couple issues. First, when using the below SQL statement.

```
SELECT `Name`,`Email`,`Phone` 
FROM `jos_breezingforms_Contest_Registration` 
GROUP BY `Contest`
```

In this table I have three dummy entries. One entry with a 'Birthday' contest and two entries with a 'Office Party' contest.  And of those three entries there is one person with two contests (Birthday & Office Party) and one person with one contest (Office Party).

That said, this entry should have grouped two individuals under Office Party and one individual with Birthday.  But it did not. It displayed only the person who had both the Birthday and Office Party; and completely disregarded (or did not display) the one individual how had Office Party contest only.

What I need for it to do is not only group by contests but also make the results of those groups expandable/collapsible so that one has click on the toggle of the contest in question to expand and see results.

I can't find anything online that offers any advise on this. Does anyone in this network have any words of wisdom for me?

Comment: Can you add a CREATE TABLE script to create the table in question, and an INSERT script to insert enough data to replicate the problem? The second part of your question to expand/collapse groups is not possible in SQL and should be a separate question.

Comment: I think your query can't be run. It should actually give you an error. You cannot SELECT columns that you don't also list in GROUP BY unless you put them into an aggregate function such as min() or max().

Comment: @Christian, I'm pretty sure MySQL allows selecting un-aggregated columns in a GROUP BY. With that being said, I don't think there's any way to do what OP is asking for. It would need to be a phpMyAdmin feature, and has nothing to do with actual SQL.

Comment: @panohh - Since the characters are limited. Here it is in parts.  Here is the create statement. 


CREATE TABLE jos_breezingforms_Contest_Registration (
    ID int(11),
    Count  int(11),
    Name varchar(50),
    Contest varchar(50),
    Other varchar(50),
    Email varchar(50),
    Phone varchar(50),
    Date date,
);

Comment: @panohh-Here are the insert statements.


INSERT INTO jos_breezingforms_Contest_Registration (Name,Contest,Other,Email,Phone,Date`)
VALUES ('Dorothy Davis', 'Birthday', '', 'someone@gmail.com', '5554443333','2019-01-16');

INSERT INTO jos_breezingforms_Contest_Registration (Name,Contest,Other,Email,Phone,Date`)
VALUES ('Dorothy Davis', 'Office Party', '', 'someone@gmail.com', '5554443333','2019-01-16');

INSERT INTO jos_breezingforms_Contest_Registration (Name,Contest,Other,Email,Phone,Date`)
VALUES ('Rhett Davis', 'Office Party', '', 'somebody@gmail.com', '6665554444','2019-01-16');

Comment: @panohh - Here is the statement I would ultimately like to use but properly since apparently i have something wrong with it.

SELECT `Name`,`Other`,`Email`,`Phone`,`Contest` count(distinct `Contest`) AS 'Count', 
FROM `jos_breezingforms_Contest_Registration`
WHERE (`Date`={fn CURDATE()})
GROUP BY `Contest`
ORDER BY `Name`

Comment: Thank you @Aioros and Christian - I'd like to include a clause in my SQL statement that allows me to set the group by field to be default collapse, but be expandable with a toggle similar to  "-/+ groupby_field_name and count" where count = the number of records in that group.  If it is a myphpadmin feature or issue then where do I go from here to implement such a feature. Is such a feature available?

Comment: There's no collapse or anything like that in SQL, no query will help with that. If you wanted something like that, phpMyAdmin (which is an application working on top of the db) would have to provide such a UI feature, executing multiple queries and under the hood, and I don't think that it does.

Comment: @aioros - I've accomplished this before but it was in sharepoint. I was hoping sql had something similar....:(  Thanks.

Comment: @panohh - It seems that {fn CURDATE()} no longer works. I'm having to use CURRENT_DATE.  That said the select query I posted should read:  SELECT 'Name','Other','Email','Phone','Contest' count(distinct Contest) AS 'Count', FROM jos_breezingforms_Contest_Registration WHERE 'Date'=CURRENT_DATE GROUP BY Contest ORDER BY Name. still not grouping properly for that table though. not listing all that it should be.